# Stackplot pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I want to use stackplot on my data. However it needs to be groupedby first. I am also hoping it would get the legend from the groupby as it would using df.plot(legend=True)

```
              Region  Dengue_Cases
Date                              
2008-01-01  Region.I      2.953926
2008-02-01  Region.I      2.183336
2008-01-01  Region.II     0.972410
2008-02-01  Region.II     9.357156
2008-01-01  Region.III    7.320599


import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 10))
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)

#ax.stackplot(df['Date'], df.groupby('Region')['Dengue_Cases'], legend=True)
```

I used the above code but I guess its wrong since it sent error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUUC, you can get what you want with `DataFrame.plot.area()`, though you need to first pivot your `DataFrame`, so that each column is a distinct region, and the indices are the dates.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9, 6))
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')

df = df.set_index('Date')
_ = df.pivot(columns='Region', values='Dengue_Cases').plot.area(ax=ax)

_ = plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.04,1), loc="upper left")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! Thanks! Really Nice!